# link the Doxygen documentation with a Java project inside Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, javadoc, doxygen

Could you tell me how to link the doxygen documentation with a Java project inside Eclipse?

Here is the background: I am involved in a C++ project, which has a Java Interface. Its document seems to be generated by doxygen rather than javadoc. I hope to use this documentation inside Eclipse, but I don't see how to. I have installed the doxygen plugin Eclox but apparently I don't see what to do next.

For information, here is the a part of my project's ./doc directory[image]./doc